# C++ build failing on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run my C++ program on my Macbook and I'm trying to run my program in VSCode by running the build task `C/C++:clang++ build active file`. However, every time I do this I get this error `ld: can't open output file for writing: /Users/admin/first/first, errno=21 for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1`

Comment: The error code 21 means that "/Users/admin/first/first" already exists and is a directory.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a simple permission problem here:

> ld: can't open output file for writing

The linker cannot write to the file specified.

**Edit**: As correctly pointed to by molbdnilo, the `error 21` is `EISDIR`, which means the *file* you are trying to write to already exists as a *directory*. So ... just this folder? :)

Comment: I changed the permissions to read and write for staff and everyone. For me (Admin) I already had read & write access. I still get the same error.

Comment: Where are you building from? can you manually `touch /Users/admin/first/first`? What's the output adding the `-v` verbose flag? Probably others :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you brew install any c++ tools? Sometimes that is the source of these issues. The program is trying to use native OS versions of things when it should use Homebrew's or vice versa.